# SQL Server: SUM numeric value but leave strings as is

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm having trouble suming a column which has both numeric and ncharvar values where the numerics are summed (and grouped) but the strings are left as is.

I.e.:

from:

```
| ID | Value |    
+----+-------+  
| a  | 4     |  
| b  | 3     |  
| c  | hello |  
| a   | 8    |  
+----+-------+
```

to:

```
| ID | Value |    
+----+-------+  
| a  | 12     |  
| b  | 3     |  
| c  | hello |   
+----+-------+
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT
   [ID],
   [CASE]
      WHEN ISNUMERIC([Value]) = 1 THEN SUM(CAST([Value] AS INT))
      ELSE [Value]
   END AS Value
FROM db
GROUP BY [ID]
```

But I get an error that "the column Value is inavlid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Comment: This is challenging because you have mixed datatypes in a single column. I would suggest fixing the data model. But if you are really stuck then something like Gordon posted will be a reasonably decent work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try_convert()`/`try_cast()` instead:

```
SELECT [ID], SUM(TRY_CAST([Value] as int))
FROM db
GROUP BY [ID];
```

Incidentally, the error that you are getting is because your `cast()` is *after* the `sum()`.  You have a syntax error because `value` is not in t he `group by`.  If you didn't you would still get a run-time error.